# Mapping two lists in R

Tags: r, list

As a toy example, suppose I have a `list.map`, whose main indices contain sub-indices that are "pointers" to some vector of two elements. Given a `test` list which just contains the "pointer" indices for every main index, I'd like to have a final list that outputs the corresponding vectors.

```
list1=list(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6))
list.map=list(list1,list1)
test=list(c(1,3),2)

> list.map
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 5 6


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 5 6

> test
[[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

**My attempt**

```
test.out=NULL
for(b in c(1,2)){
  test.out[[b]]=as.vector(sapply(test[[b]],function(x) list.map[[b]][[x]]))
}

> test.out
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 3 4
```

This is isn't the most elegant approach and ideally I'd have hundreds of the main indices indexed by `b` in my `for` loop. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map(function(x, y) unlist(x[y]), list.map, test)

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tidyverse` syntax would be

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(list.map, test, `[`) %>%
                  map(unlist)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 5 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4
```